# Clear button in md-input

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Are there any clear button included with md-input of type Search? I know that I can just add an clear button outside or the search input component, but I would rather like to get it as part of the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with existing version of angular material (v0.9.0) but is targeted to v0.10.0. See more information here: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2802#issuecomment-101764802

However, there is a Angular directive that might be used as a workaround. https://github.com/dcohenb/angular-clear-input

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working

Answer (score 2):

I solve it using a negative `margin-right`

```css
.search {
    md-content.md-default-theme {
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .search-cancel {
        color: white !important;
        fill: white;
        border: none;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        margin: 8px 0 0 -36px;
        overflow: visible;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: background 0.15s linear;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        &:hover {
            background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
            <div layout="row" class="search">
                <md-content flex="90" layout-padding>
                    <md-input-container md-no-float>
                        <md-icon md-svg-icon="search" class="name"></md-icon>
                        <input ng-model="search" type="search" title="Search" placeholder="Search">
                    </md-input-container>
                </md-content>
                <md-content flex layout-padding>
                    <md-icon ng-show="search" md-svg-icon="md-close" class="search-cancel"
                             ng-click="search=''"></md-icon>
                </md-content>
            </div>
```

The containing `md-content` also needs `overflow-visible` so that the icon is not clipped.